# Angular method not returns from if statement

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

This method never returns true. Eventhough it displays that true  message in console. Why this behaviour ?

```
 purgeEmptyRows(obj: any) :Observable<boolean>  {
          let isEmpty = false;
          Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          if( obj[key] != null) {
            if(typeof obj[key] != "object"){
            console.log("true");
              return Observable.of(true);
            }
          }else {
            isEmpty = false;
          }

          })
          return Observable.of(isEmpty);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning an Observable with the `true` inside of it. So you have two options.

First option, change the function to return a simple boolean instead of an Observable.

Second option, subscribe to the observable you are returning.

For the first option, do the following:

```
purgeEmptyRows(obj: any) :boolean  {
    let isEmpty = false;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if( obj[key] != null) {
            if(typeof obj[key] != "object"){
                console.log("true");
                isEmpty = true;
            }
        } else {
            isEmpty = false;
        }

    });
    return isEmpty;
}
```

For the second option,  you still need to change your code to be the following:

```
purgeEmptyRows(obj: any) : Observable<boolean>  {
    let isEmpty = false;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if( obj[key] != null) {
            if(typeof obj[key] != "object"){
                console.log("true");
                isEmpty = true;
            }
        } else {
            isEmpty = false;
        }

    });
    return Observable.of(isEmpty);
}
```

And then, when you call the function, you will call subscribe to the result. Here is an example:

```
const obs = purgeEmptyRows(rows);
obs.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'. since my return type is Observable I can't return true/false;

Comment: That's true. If you're going to change what the function returns, you have to ask change the return type in the function signature. So you would change the return type from `Observable<boolean>` to `boolean`.

Comment: if return type is boolean then I cant subscribe . Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'boolean'.ts(2339)

Comment: I just did some edits to add the two different options that you have.

Comment: No, that is not the logic. if its true then return from the function

Comment: Cool. Then make that change. I don't understand what you are saying there. I am trying to help, though. I promise.

Comment: thank for your suggestion. Ill be using this code. Just mentioned if its true I don't want that for loop to execute any more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you did not assign `isEmpty` inside.

```
if(typeof obj[key] != "object"){
   console.log("true");
  return Observable.of(true);
}
```

It should look like this

```
if(typeof obj[key] != "object"){
  isEmpty = true
}
```

Comment: No, that is not the logic. if its true then return from the function.